# How do I remove a single trailing string from another string in Rust?

Tags: string, rust

Given the following two strings:

```
let subject: &str = "zoop-12";
let trail: &str "-12";
```

How would I go about removing `trail` from `subject` only once? I would only like to do this in the case that `subject` has these characters at its end, so in a case like this I would like nothing removed:

```
let subject: &str "moop-12loop";
let not_a_trail: &str = "-12";
```

I'm okay with either being a `String` or `&str`, but I choose to use `&str` for brevity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your specification is very similar to [`trim_end_matches`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim_end_matches), but you want to trim only one suffix whereas `trim_end_matches` will trim all of them.

Here is a function that uses [`ends_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.ends_with) along with slicing to remove only one suffix:

```
fn remove_suffix<'a>(s: &'a str, p: &str) -> &'a str {
    if s.ends_with(p) {
        &s[..s.len() - p.len()]
    } else {
        s
    }
}
```

The slice will never panic because if the pattern matches, `s[s.len() - p.len()]` is guaranteed to be on a character boundary.

Answer (score 10):

There is also [str::strip_suffix](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.strip_suffix)

```rust
fn remove_suffix<'a>(s: &'a str, suffix: &str) -> &'a str {

    match s.strip_suffix(suffix) {
        Some(s) => s,
        None => s
    }
}

fn main() {
    let subject: &str = "zoop-12";
    //let subject: &str = "moop-12loop";
    let trail: &str = "-12";

    let stripped_subject = remove_suffix(subject, trail);
    
    println!("{}", stripped_subject);
}
```